# Ошибка: 0x80070002 при удалении Ubuntu в Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, microsoft-store

При первой  установке Ubuntu 18.04 из магазина Windows 10 , терминал постоянно зависал на моменте:

> this may take a few minutes...

После жесткой перезагрузки системы и запуска Bash Ubuntu выходит это :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее пробую удалить подсистему:

```
lxrun /uninstall /full
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно все вернуть и еще раз установить Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

удалилось стандартно через "удаление программ в windows", а терминал висел, потому что на ssd было < 10 гб. свободного места.. )